# Fortify : Path Manipulation in C - White List Implementation doesn't work - fopen issue

Tags: c, fopen, fortify, path-manipulation

Hello everyone I have a fortify issue "Path manipulation" it produced by fopen use. According with fortify I could implement a white list in order to fix it, so there have my white list validator:

white_list.c

```
#define BUFF_WHITE_LIST_FILE 200
const char *white_list_validator( char *variable )
{
  FILE *fp = NULL;
  ssize_t read;
  char * line = NULL;
  size_t len = 0;
  char white_list_file_buff[BUFF_WHITE_LIST_FILE];
  if ( __secure_getenv("WHITE_LIST_FILE") == NULL )
    return NULL;
  else
  {
    strncpy(white_list_file_buff,
         __secure_getenv("WHITE_LIST_FILE"),sizeof(white_list_file_buff)-1);
    fp = fopen(white_list_file_buff,"r");
    if ( fp == NULL )
        return NULL;
    else
    {
        while( (read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1 )
        {
            if ( strncmp(line,variable,read - 1) == 0 ){
                fclose(fp);
                return variable;
            }

        }
        fclose(fp);

    }
    if(line)
        free(line);
 }
 return NULL;
}
```

it return NULL if it doesn't find the **variable** inside White.list (*) or return a pointer to char if it find it

```
int main( int argc, char **argv ) {

    FILE *fp = NULL;
    char mrd[50]={0};
    const char *ptr = white_list_validator(argv[1]);

    if ( argv[1] == NULL )
        return -1;

    if(ptr==NULL)
        return -1;
    else
    {
        strncpy(mrd,ptr,sizeof(mrd)-1);
        printf("variables found : %s\n",mrd);

        fp = fopen(mrd,"w");  <------   SINK
        if ( fp == NULL ){
                printf("line 22\n");
                exit(1);
        }
        fprintf(fp, "%s %s %s %d", "We", "are", "in", 2077);
        fclose(fp);

    }

  return 0;
 }
```

but when I run the fortify report appear a manipulation path vulnerability in fopen, I do not know why .You can see in the code, before that manage to file with fopen it validated for a white_list_validator.
so anybody has an idea why it does not work correctly?

NOTE(*) : export WHITE_LIST_FILE=/path/White.list

cat White.list

test1

test2

something

When I run the binary:

./white_list something

variables found : something

Comment: There is an `else if` clause on line 22 of the first code, which does not follow a matching `if`. It also has a memory leak because at `return variable;` there is no `free(line)`.

Comment: **[cargo-cult alert]** The use of `strncpy()` here is dangerous ( it allmost always is) , since `white_list_file_buf` is not initialized with a final NUL byte.

Comment: sorry is a typed mistake , it will be:
             if ( strncmp(line,variable,read - 1) == 0 ){
                fclose(fp);
                return variable;
            }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick search of `__secure_getenv` lead to this page:

https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/LSB_1.1.0/gLSB/baselib---secure-getenv-1.html

Quote:

> `__secure_getenv(name)` has the same specification as `getenv(name)` with the exception that if the program
>   is running SUID or SGID enabled, the result is always `NULL`.

So, the question is: is your program running with set SUID or SGID bits? As
far as I can see, `__secure_getenv` has been renamed to `secure_getenv` (my man page says it appeared in glibc 2.17).
You should use that instead.

Another cause could be: if the length of the source string is longer than the `size` argument of `strncpy`,
it won't add the `'\0'` terminating byte. When using `strncpy` you should
always make sure to write the `'\0'` terminating byte.

> *man strcpy*
>
> ```
> #include <string.h>
> char *strncpy(char *dest, const char *src, size_t n);
> ```
>
> The  `strncpy()` function is similar, except that at most `n` bytes of `src` are copied.
>   **Warning**: If there is no null byte among the first `n` bytes of `src`,
>   the string placed in dest will not be null-terminated.

`white_list_file_buff` might not be `'\0'`-terminated, thus `fopen` fails.
But you say you did `export WHITE_LIST_FILE=/path/White.list`. Is
`/path/White.list` the real value you used or some path that is longer than
200 characters?

Also your code here

```
while( (read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1 )
{
    else if ( strncmp(line,variable,read - 1) == 0 ){
        fclose(fp);
        return variable;
    }

}
```

is either wrong or did you forget to paste the whole code? There is no
previous `if` for that `else`.

Assuming that you've made a copy&paste error, how is the format if
`White.list`? Every line contains nothing but the name of variables? Your
`strncmp` compare the whole line you know, and if you want to match only a
substring, you should use `strstr`.

Comment: I'll change strncmp by strstr and in the fortify report appear again path manipulation

Comment: @MiguelÁngelRetamozoSanchez can you post a few lines of your `White.list` file`. What is the real value of `WHITE_LIST_FILE`?

Comment: cat White.list
test1
test2
something




run :
./white_list something

it sould be found it , becuase "something" word is inside White.list

Comment: @MiguelÁngelRetamozoSanchez comments don't show lines, can you please post that in your question?

Comment: @MiguelÁngelRetamozoSanchez I compiled your code (using `secure_getenv` and `strstr) and the program worked fine. I think either `WHITE_LIST_FILE` is wrong or the content of `White.lst` is wrong.

Comment: Yup me too , in the report it still apeear  the path manipulation :S

Answer (score 1):

Fortify generally will not recognize whitelist validation as fixing the issue - once you've verified the routine, you need to teach it that this is a validation routine.   This will ensure any trace that correctly validates with this routine is not reported.

You should ensure you've addressed the other comments, and validated the underlying routine itself is secure.  Then you should register the whitelist routine as a validation routine by adding a custom rule via the rules editor.  Best way to do this is a validation / cleansing rule that adds a taint flag of taintFlag="VALIDATED_PATH_MANIPULATION" - the sink rules for path manipulation should not report issues with this taint.

For more information on using the taint flags see
https://community.softwaregrp.com/dcvta86296/attachments/dcvta86296/fortify-discussions/2950/1/HP_Fortify_SCA_Custom_Rules_Guide_4.21.pdf

Comment: VALIDATED_PATH_MANIPULATION is a fortify variable? , it means that I can  use like a flag inside my white_list_validator function ?

Comment: It's a taint - you can taint a flow with any value via a rule, but some values (such as the validated taints) are recognized by the Fortify native rules and they will not report issues that are marked as validated.

Answer (score 0):

Your whitelist approach approach obtains the name of the whitelist from an environment variable.  This is so easily manipulable as to not even justify the added complexity of implementing a whitelist in the first place, and it certainly should be cause for its own path-manipulation vulnerability.  Using `__secure_getenv()` to obtain the value doesn't really help; it just means that your program won't work if run in a secure context.

Even if the whitelist's own path were fixed at compile time, you're still obtaining the whitelisted paths from an external source.  That's harder to manipulate than totally unverified user input, but it doesn't really resolve the vulnerability.

If you cannot compile your whitelist into the program, then consider instead hardcoding a whitelist of path prefixes and a whitelist of characters that may appear in the remaining path components.  It's unclear whether Fortify would actually recognize this as resolving the issue, but that would be sufficient for me to be satisfied to set the issue's analysis to "Not an issue".

Comment: I'll  put __secure_getenv insted getenv because fortify don't take like a vulnerability , but I put the complite path insted __secure_getenv and fortify doesn't take the a vulnerability